# Do Elements of Odd Order Form a Subgroup

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693873/odd-torsion-of-elliptic-curves-are-isomorphic) on the odd torsion points of elliptic curves. The accepted answer states that the "coprime-to-$p$" points form a subgroup (so, in particular, the $C_{oddtors}(\mathbb{Q})$ would form a subgroup). **However, I don't understand why this is a subgroup.**

More generally, given an **abelian** group, do the elements of odd order form a subgroup? I cannot convince myself that the sum of two elements with odd order will necessarily have odd order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say we have an abelian group with two elements $a, b$ of order $o_a, o_b$ respectively, and let $d = \operatorname{lcm}(o_a, o_b)$. Then $d\cdot(a+b) = 0$, so the order of $a+b$ must divide $d$. If $o_a$ and $o_b$ are both odd, then $d$ is odd, and thus the order of $a + b$ must also be odd.

There is nothing special about "odd" here, we can use "coprime to $n$" for any natural number $n$ in place of "odd".

Answer (score 5):

In a finite abelian group $G$, the order of the product $ab$ (additively written the sum) is a divisor of 
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(a),\operatorname{ord}(b)).
$$
The lcm of two odd numbers is odd. Note that the torsion group of an elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$ is a finite abelian group.

Reference:

[Order of products of elements in a finite Abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424097/order-of-products-of-elements-in-a-finite-abelian-group)